# Duplicate collections in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am currently trying to solve an issue with our current on-premise TFS 2010 Server where I have 2 collections and both of my project collections were set to offline due to some tinkering with trying to upgrade to on-premise TFS 2015.

Whenever I try to activate the desired collection, I am getting the following error:

> TF253021:The following team project is duplicated in at least two team
>   project collections: ProjectName. The collection cannot start while
>   the duplication exists. You must delete this project from all but one
>   of the collections before the collection can be started. The project
>   exists in the following collections: CollectionA, CollectionB.

I also had a look at each of their settings, and apparently the database connection string for both collections are pointing towards the same SQL Server instance and the same database. Both collections also have the same number and names of all team projects too.

I'm thinking of deleting one of the collection and its projects, but I fear that if I do it, it may delete the same collection and settings for the second project collection that I'm trying to set online.

I'm wondering if anybody has encountered this issue and what steps have he/she has done to fix it.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd call support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten yourself in a remarkable situation, which may need Microsoft support to chime in. Even with creative backups I'd be unsure whether you'd get yourself in an unsupported end-situation.

If you have a backup of the whole situation before you started this experiment, I'd recommend going back to that.

You may find yourself in a catch-22 situation, since TFS 2010 has passed it's support lifecycle. Mentioning it happened while preparing for a TFS 2015 upgrade may convince them.

You can find the contact details here:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing! We managed to deep dive in TFS' SQL database and removed the collections from there. It was a hard task looking at each one of the db objects, but tinkering with TFS's database (with shivers) did the trick.